# How do I create a circulant matrix?

Tags: matrix

How do I create an $n \times n$ [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)?

I couldn't make [ToeplitzMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToeplitzMatrix.html) do it for me.

Comment: It's right there in the docs for `ToeplitzMatrix`, under Properties & Relations.  Search the doc page for "circulant".

Comment: @kglr beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
cm = ToeplitzMatrix[{c0, c1, c2, c3}, RotateRight[Reverse[{c0, c1, c2, c3}]]];
cm  // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: And this method is the fastest...

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need to use `ToeplitzMatrix`?

What about following?

```
MatrixForm@Transpose@NestList[RotateRight, #, Length[#]-1] &@{1, 2, 3, 
  4}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Reverse /@ Partition[ {c1, c2, c3, c0}, 4, 1, {1, 1}, {c1, c2, c3, c0}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

or more simple :

```
Reverse /@ Partition[{c1, c2, c3, c0}, 4, 1, {1, 1}]
```